# Extend an action in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, extension-methods

I'm building a controller that sets the same variables in several actions. Something like this:

```
def one
  @a = 1
  @b=2
  @test = "One"
end

def two
  @a = 1
  @b = 2
  @test = "Two"
end
```

I'm aware that I could call a method to fill in the variable assignments, but I'm wondering how one would do this the "Best Practice" way. I got ambitious and tried...

```
def master 
  @a = 1
  @b = 2
end

def one < master
  @test = "One"
end

def two < master
  @test = "Two"
end
```

But this arose to no avail. What does the SO community suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<` is used for inheritance in Ruby and cannot be used on methods. In Rails you can call `before_filter` for this purpose.

```
before_filter :master
```

if you want it for all methods in the controller, or

```
before_filter :master, :only => [:one, :two]
```

if you want it for these methods only.